# Can I set windows sonsole width in Node.js?

Tags: windows, node.js, console

Can I Set Windows Console width in Node.js?

```
process.stdout.columns =300;
process.stdout.rows = 300;

console.log(process.stdout.columns)
console.log(process.stdout.rows)
```

it doesn't work?

Comment: what does: console.log(process.stdout.columns) console.log(process.stdout.rows) output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's not very complicated.

```
var COORD=
refStruct({

     X: ref.types.int16
    ,Y: ref.types.int16

})


//kernel32
this.kernel32 = new ffi.Library('kernel32', {

      'SetConsoleScreenBufferSize': ['bool', ['int32', COORD]]

    , 'GetStdHandle': ['int32', ['long']]

});

this.setConsoleBufferSize = function (colume,row) {

    var handle = winapi.kernel32.GetStdHandle(-11);
    var x = winapi.kernel32.SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(handle, new COORD({

          X: colume
        , Y: row

    }));

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments and the documentation for process.stdout I would say that .columns and .rows are read only.

I've been looking for a while and it does not seem like there is any way to resize the console window from node.